# CUDA Driver API equivalent to cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig

Tags: cuda

Comparing the CUDA (latest, v11.3 as of writing) driver API with the runtime API reveals that the runtime API has function

```
__host__ ​cudaError_t cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig ( cudaFuncCache cacheConfig )
    Sets the preferred cache configuration for the current device.
```

and it seems the driver API has no equivalent function. Any insight to why that is and is there a way to set the device-wide cache configuration with the driver API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding function is `cuCtxSetCacheConfig`  documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html#group__CUDA__CTX_1g54699acf7e2ef27279d013ca2095f4a3).

The reason for the difference is that the [driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#driver-api) focuses on [context](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#context) behavior.  The runtime API generally posits that for a particular process owner, there is only [one context per device](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#initialization).  (Therefore it generally has a "device" in view instead of a context.)  The same is not necessarily the case for the driver API. So you you are given the ability to set it per-context.

If you only have one context per device, that control is effectively "device-wide".

Comment: Thanks! Good to know.